# Truncate Table locking sys views

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, truncate, snapshot-isolation

We have a proc that runs `Truncate Table` inside an Snapshot transaction.  This seems to be causing a `LOCK_M_S` lock that blocks the sys view `sys.partitions`.

Is there a convenient work around for this?  I like the efficiency of not taking excess logs that happens with truncate, but don't want to lock up my `sys.partitions`.

I'm happy to post the code upon request, but I'm pretty sure this is some behavior of `Truncate` being inside a Snapshot transaction. that i'm just unaware of.

Comment: If the TRUNCATE blocks `sys.partitions` from being accessed, then I don't think that the problem is the truncate - a `DELETE * FROM`  should have the same effect. The problem is that it is inside a transaction, and that the pending actions on the table are blocking the `sys.partitions` view... somehow.  As a question, have you tried the statement `SELECT * FROM sys.partitions WITH(NOLOCK)`

Comment: @LaughingVergil,  WITH(NOLOCK) is actually still blocked... I'll post the blocking query

Comment: As another thing to check - apparently, the `sys.partitions` view can lock/block, but it depends on what columns are selected. Try limiting the columns selected from the view, and see if that works.

Answer (score 3):

Locking for truncate and delete is different. As for locking TRUNCATE behave more like 'ALTER TABLE' than DELETE.

From Microsoft documentation:
[TRUNCATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
"When the DELETE statement is executed using a row lock, each row in the table is locked for deletion. TRUNCATE TABLE always locks the table (including a schema (SCH-M) lock) and page but not each row".

As you can see, there is a schema lock on the whole table.